# Can only use glClear(xy|xy), no drawings are "taken"

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d

I set up the OpenGL Context correctly I guess and I can only call glClear() successfully (the color of background changes). When I am trying to draw something, nothing gets viewed ._.

```
int main()
{   
    // Opening a Window
    h3d::Window App(h3d::Vec2<unsigned int>(800,600),L"Test",h3d::Style::Default);
    // Init Extensions
    glewInit();

    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
    //Set up the orthographic projection so that coordinates (0, 0) are in the top left
    //and the minimum and maximum depth is -10 and 10. To enable depth just put in
    //glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, -10, 10);

    //Back to the modelview so we can draw stuff 
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); //Clear the screen and depth buffer

    int i = 0;
    App.setActive();
    while (App.isOpen())
    {   
        cout << "new loop " << i << endl; i++;

        App.update();

        if(i%2 == 0)
            glClearColor(1.0, 0.75, 0.5, 1.0);
        else 
            glClearColor(1.0, 0.75, 1.0, 0.5);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2f(0.0,0.0);
        glVertex2f(1.0,0.0);
        glVertex2f(1.0,1.0);
        glVertex2f(0.0,1.0);
        glEnd();

        App.swapBuffers();
    } 
}
```

So the window opens correctly and there is a alternating background color.
My drawings are still not in the screen.

Comment: Assuming this `h3d::Window` constructor is creating a leagcy context / compatibility profile, you should see a _single_ black pixel at the top left corner of your window. Are you sure that isn't there?

Answer (score 2):

Your `glOrtho` call makes it so that your world space is 800 units on the X axis and 600 units on the Y axis. The box you're making goes from (0, 0) to (1, 1), so you should see a single black pixel on the top left.

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(0.0,0.0);
glVertex2f(400.0,0.0);
glVertex2f(400.0,300.0);
glVertex2f(0.0,300.0);
glEnd();
```

Will create a black square that takes up the top-left quadrant of your screen. From there you should be able to make whatever you want.